# is OrientDB using the index in gremlin-java?

Tags: java, orientdb, gremlin

I'm creating a very simple graph database structure to assess the performance of OrientDB (2.1.5) and I'm seing such terrible performance that I must be doing it wrong. The following on a `com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraph` (2.6.0):

```
g.createKeyIndex("typehint", Vertex.class)
g.createKeyIndex("fqn", Vertex.class)

// add a bunch of Vertices with "typehint" and "fqn" values

// then issue queries for vertices with a composite key
// (btw, I don't know how to enforce this as a composite key)
g.query().has("typehint", ...).has("fqn", ...)
```

but this is ludicrously slow!

Is OrientDB unable to handle the chaining of `has` calls? What's the workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using subclasses of V when you create your vertices? If yes, please take a look at the documentation about the right way to create an index: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Graph-Database-Tinkerpop.html#using-indices. Then, call

```
g.query().labels("MyClass").has("typehint", ...)
```

Comment: ah, thanks I didn't know about `labels`. My problem was reading the gremlin docs (which are awful). I also discovered these docs last night and found out how to add `class:` labels AND simple composite keys. It was effectively the documentation you've pointed me at so I'll mark this as the answer and add more details.

Comment: hmm, I don't seem to have `labels` on my `query()` object. Are you using a newer API?

Comment: there is a method called `getVerticesOfClass` on `OrientBaseGraph`, that seems to do what your `labels` says. Maybe `labels` is specific to your database implementation?

Comment: Yes, you should cast .query() to OrientGraphQuery class. Example `Iterable<Vertex> rcs = ((OrientGraphQuery) db.query()).labels("rawCategory").vertices();`

Comment: I think I'd rather use the `getVerticesOfClass` method.

Comment: aah, yours is for query usage, which might be better if I'm doing further restrictions. That sucks.